# Jackson XML deserialize to ObjectNode, cannot get array value

Tags: java, arrays, xml, jackson

When I use jackson deserialization xml, xml has node is array, java bean has attribute is ObjectNode, ObjectNode cannot get array value,Here is the sample code
jackson version: 2.10.5

java bean:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "TX")
public class ServiceBusReq<T> {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "TX_HEADER")
    private ServiceBusHeaderReq txHeader;
    
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "TX_EMB")
    private String txEmb;

    /**
     **Notice:** I cannot specify the creation of an Entity object because the content received here is variable
     */    
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ENTITY")
    private ObjectNode entity;

    private T msgObject;
}
```

XML content:

```
<TX> 
  <TX_HEADER> 
    <SYS_HDR_LEN/>  
    <SYS_PKG_VRSN>01</SYS_PKG_VRSN>  
    <SYS_TTL_LEN/>  
    <SYS_REQ_SEC_ID>402205</SYS_REQ_SEC_ID>  
    <SYS_SND_SEC_ID>402205</SYS_SND_SEC_ID> 
  </TX_HEADER> 
  <TX_EMB/>  
  <ENTITY> 
    <USER_NAME>xcc</USER_NAME> 
    <COMPANYS>
        <COMPANY>
            <COMPANYNAME>NAME-1</COMPANYNAME>
        </COMPANY>
        <COMPANY>
            <COMPANYNAME>NAME-2</COMPANYNAME>
        </COMPANY>
</COMPANYS>
  </ENTITY> 
</TX>
```

main :

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = XmlMapper.xmlBuilder().build();
ServiceBusReq serviceBusReq = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, ServiceBusReq.class);
System.out.println(serviceBusReq);
```

result:

```
ServiceBusReq(txHeader=ServiceBusHeaderReq(sysHdrLen=null, sysPkgVrsn=01, sysTtlLen=null, sysReqSecId=402205, sysSndSecId=402205, sysTxCode=null, sysTxVrsn=null, sysTxType=null, sysReserved=null, sysEvtTraceId=null, sysSndSerialNo=null, sysPkgType=null, sysMsgLen=null, sysIsEncrypted=null, sysEncryptType=null, sysCompressType=null, sysEmbMsgLen=null, sysReqTime=null, sysTimeLeft=null, sysPkgStsType=null), txBody=null, txEmb=null, entity={"USER_NAME":"xcc","COMPANYS":{"COMPANY":{"COMPANYNAME":"NAME-2"}}}, msgObject=null)
```

The reason I use ObjectNode instead of classes is because classes are uncertain. I want COMPANYS to get an array,who can help me,Thank you!  if not use ObjectNode, what can use

Answer (score 0):

For lists there is the specific [`JacksonXmlElementWrapper`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlElementWrapper.html) annotation that must be used with the [`JacksonXmlProperty`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlProperty.html#localName--) indicating the wrapper list tag; focusing on the xml structure you want to deserialize the xml structure below to a list:

```
<ENTITY> 
    <USER_NAME>xcc</USER_NAME> 
    <COMPANYS>
        <COMPANY>
            <COMPANYNAME>NAME-1</COMPANYNAME>
        </COMPANY>
        <COMPANY>
            <COMPANYNAME>NAME-2</COMPANYNAME>
        </COMPANY>
   </COMPANYS>
</ENTITY>
```

This structure can be converted to an `Entity` class containing a `Companies` class field containg a `List<Company>` field like below:

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) //<-- up to you insert other properties
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "TX")
public class ServiceBusReq {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ENTITY")
    private Entity entity;
}

@Data
public class Entity {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "USER_NAME")
    private String username;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "COMPANYS") 
    private Companies companies;
}

@Data
public class Companies {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "COMPANY")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Company> companies;
}

@Data
public class Company {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "COMPANYNAME")
    private String companyName;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I cannot specify the creation of an Entity object because the content received here is variable. Entity maybe is
<ENTITY> 
    <COUNTRY>U.S</COUNTRY> 
    <ADDRESS>Nottingham</ADDRESS>
</ENTITY>

Comment: @EverSpring You are welcome,  if you have different types probably you have to define one subclass for one type, try to experiment the different scenarios starting from the code I posted.

Comment: I have solved the problem. In the jackson-databind github, issue 2732 , the author resolve. Here is my solution:  Upgrade jackson-databind to version 2.12.0